# Passing data from controller to modal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm am trying to get data from a database table and passing it to the modal but it is saying the array I am passing in undefined. Here is my Controller:

```
public function displayLocNotesForModal() {
    $notesLoc = Note::all();
    
    return view('/components/callCenter/modalLocNotes', ['notesLoc' => $notesLoc]);
}
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('/components/callCenter/modalLocNotes', 'App\Http\Controllers\CallCenter\NoteController@displayLocNotesForModal');
```

Here is my modal:

```html
<div class="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:ml-4 sm:text-left">
    <h3 class="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900" id="modal-headline">
        Location #{{ $title }} Notes
    </h3>
    <div class="mt-2">
        <p class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">
            {{-- {{ $slot }} --}}
            @foreach($notesLoc as $notes)
                @if($notes == $title)
                    works    
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: views are accessed by dot notation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#nested-view-directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be like below, assuming the components folder is in your `resources/views` folder

```
return view('components.callCenter.modalLocNotes', ['notesLoc' => $notesLoc]);
```

Also providing a link to docs [Laravel nested view directories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#nested-view-directories)